# Using Telnet In Java

Tags: java, swing, bash, terminal, telnet

I am working on a Terminal application that allows people to execute bash commands from a Swing GUI. I run into the following problem when trying to execute telnet (to connect to the Star Wars ASCII thing):

> telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl
>
> Connection closed by foreign host.
>
> Trying 94.142.241.111... Connected to towel.blinkenlights.nl. Escape
>   character is '^]'.

Here's my code:

```
package me.nrubin29.jterminal;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class JTerminal extends JFrame {

    private JTextPane area = new JTextPane();
    private JTextField input = new JTextField("Input");

    private SimpleAttributeSet inputSAS = new SimpleAttributeSet(), output = new SimpleAttributeSet(), error = new SimpleAttributeSet();

    private File workingFolder = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getDefaultDirectory();

    public JTerminal() throws IOException {
        super("JTerminal");

        getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        StyleConstants.setForeground(inputSAS, Color.GREEN);
        StyleConstants.setBackground(inputSAS, Color.BLACK);

        StyleConstants.setForeground(output, Color.WHITE);
        StyleConstants.setBackground(output, Color.BLACK);

        StyleConstants.setForeground(error, Color.RED);
        StyleConstants.setBackground(error, Color.BLACK);

        input.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    try {
                        String command = input.getText();
                        if (command.equals("")) return;

                        setTitle("JTerminal (" + command.split(" ")[0] + ")");

                        input.setText("");
                        input.setEditable(false);

                        write(inputSAS, command);

                        ProcessBuilder bashBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("bash").directory(workingFolder);
                        bashBuilder.environment().put("SUDO_ASKPASS", "SUDO_ASKPASS");
                        Process bash = bashBuilder.start();

                        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(bash.getOutputStream());
                        outputStreamWriter.write(command);
                        outputStreamWriter.close();

                        int code = bash.waitFor();

                        writeStream(bash.getErrorStream(), error);
                        writeStream(bash.getInputStream(), output);

                        input.setEditable(true);
                        setTitle("JTerminal");

                        if (code == 0 && command.split(" ").length > 1) workingFolder = new File(command.split(" ")[1]);

                        bash.destroy();

                    } catch (Exception ex) { error(ex); }
                }
            }

            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
        });

        area.setBackground(Color.black);
        area.setCaretColor(Color.green);
        area.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 14));
        area.setEditable(false);

        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(area);
        pane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN));
        pane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        pane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 460));

        input.setBackground(Color.black);
        input.setForeground(Color.green);
        input.setCaretColor(Color.green);
        input.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 14));
        input.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN));

        add(pane);
        add(input);

        Dimension DIM = new Dimension(640, 480);
        setPreferredSize(DIM);
        setSize(DIM);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(true);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

        input.requestFocus();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new JTerminal();
    }

    private void write(SimpleAttributeSet attributeSet, String... lines) {
        try {
            if (lines.length == 0) return;
            for (String line : lines) {
                area.getStyledDocument().insertString(area.getStyledDocument().getLength(), line + "\n", attributeSet);
            }
            area.getStyledDocument().insertString(area.getStyledDocument().getLength(), "\n", attributeSet);
        }
        catch (Exception e) { error(e); }
    }

    private void error(Exception e) {
        write(error, "An error has occured: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        e.printStackTrace(); //TODO: temp.
    }

    private void writeStream(InputStream s, SimpleAttributeSet color) {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s));

            ArrayList<String> strs = new ArrayList<String>();

            while(reader.ready()) strs.add(reader.readLine());

            if (strs.size() > 0) write(color, strs.toArray(new String[strs.size()]));
        }
        catch (Exception e) { error(e); }
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having? It looks like you're successfully making a telnet connection.

Comment: `Connection closed by foreign host.` without showing any Star Wars :(. Running the same command in the real Terminal works.

Comment: So it's just not possible using a Process?

Comment: It's possible but not easy; you're probably better off with a different approach. `telnet` and some similar utilities really expect to be on the other end of a live `tty`, not just a non-interactive stream.

Comment: That's fine. I didn't make this program just for `telnet`, but I noticed that `telnet` didn't work so I was wondering if there was an easy fix.

Comment: Writing terminal emulators is hard. If you think you really need one, embed a component in preference to trying to roll your own.

Comment: The main reason why I'm writing this is so I can try to use it on my locked down school computer. I highly doubt anything more than `ls` will work, but it's still fun to tell your friends that you "bypassed the school security."

Comment: [DragonConsole](http://code.google.com/p/dragonconsole/‎) maybe?

Comment: Unless you have the OK from the school it is not cool to bypass security.  Have you considered the trouble that you are potentially causing to the computer administrators and the amount of money and time it costs.  What happens if you are successful and the person responsible for the computer loses her job.

Comment: I would not even attempt anything harmful. It's just cool to `ls` and `mkdir` with a custom console. My friend are the Facebook computer user types.

Comment: Unfortunately your fun may turn out to be a lot of work for the computer admins.

Comment: Nothing that requires `sudo` would work, so don't worry. I'm not going to go around touting this great console that bypasses school "restrictions" or else all the Java fun would be over for everyone :/